# Storm acking and failing

Tags: java, groovy, apache-storm

The bolts we are using are all based on `BaseBasicBolt`, which is supposed to ensure that the input tuple for `execute` gets acked by default. After reading the documentation, it appeared we were not doing this right as we were not failing tuples when an exception was caught. So let's say your topology looks like this, where all bolts are `BaseBasicBolts`:

```
Spout -> Bolt A -> Bolt B -> Bolt C
```

If an error happens in `Bolt B` we now call this:

```
basicOutputCollector.getOutputter().fail(inputTuple)
```

Is that enough to ensure that a failure at `Bolt B` will cause the tuple that failed at B to get kicked out of the topology?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the right word for it is "kicked". If you anchor that tuple through the whole chain

```
Spout -> Bolt A -> Bolt B
```

then the `fail()` method in Bolt B will have the effect of calling the method `fail()` in the Spout. The Spout `fail()` method will receive the ID of the root tuple of the tuple you've just failed. The root tuple is the tuple that first came out of the spout and caused a chain of new tuples which includes the failed tuple in Bolt B, for example

```
root tuple -> tuple A -> tuple B
```

It is up to you to do something about it or maybe nothing at all. But the problem is that your failed tuple could leave an undesired trail in your chain. For example the tuple A can cause an update to a counter in Bolt A but after you fail tuple B in Bolt B that update can now be invalid.

So what I am trying to say is that, in this case, a tuple cannot be kicked from the topology because in some sense it already went through it (partially).